# Start an Activity which holds an Fragment, but need to press physical Back button twice to go back

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I followed the [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) example (down in the page) created a list in a main Activity , when list item is selected I start an DetailActivity which adds a DetailFragment to container .

(I simplified the example code, I didn't implement the landscape mode thing, just simply start DetailActivity when a list row is selected.)

In MainActivity, when list item is clicked I do:

```
 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(int index) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("index", index);
      startActivity(intent);
}
```

My **DetailActivity.java** :

```
    public static class DetailActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.
                DetailsFragment details = new DetailsFragment();
                details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

               //There is no layout xml for DetailActivity, we add the fragment programmatically to the activity.  
                FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();
                fragTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, details);
                fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
```

The DetailFragment.java :

```
public static class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
        DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

        // Supply index input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

    }
}
}
```

I run my app, when I selecte a row, the DetailActivity is launched with the DetailFragment being shown on screen.

**But I need to press physical Back button twice in order to go back the the list of MainActivity**. Why I need to press twice back button?

I am testing on Android 4.4.4 device.

Comment: @DerGolem PHY means physical, here I mean physical back button of the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're adding the fragment at runtime.  The first press of the back button undoes the add of the fragment.  The second finishes the activity.  To prevent this, don't add the transaction where you first load the fragment to the back stack.

Comment: this is your enemy: fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);